# can not build pjsip for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, pjsip

I was trying to build the pjsip library according to the instruction given here

http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Windows-Phone

i followed each step,but the following error occurs

error CS0006: Metadata file 'F:\Windows-Phone-Wordspace\Pjsip\pjsip-apps\src\pjsua\wp\lib\PjsuaWP.BackEnd.winmd' could not be found

i went to the pjsip-apps\src\pjsua\wp\lib directory and found that the folder is empty.

what could be done to properly build the sample on windows phone 8 ?

Comment: So what did you do to fix this error ??

Answer (score 0):

http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Windows-Phone

Set your config_site.h to the following:

```
#define PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_PORTAUDIO 0
#define PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_WMME 0
#define PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_WASAPI 1
```

go through solution and set all

```
PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_WMME 0
```

at ..\pjmedia\include\pjmedia-audiodev\config.h at Ln 112 too

OR

add ;!PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_PORTAUDIO;!PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_WMME;PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_WASAPI

to your project build options (at pjsua_wp or ypur own one)